# How can I change the layout manager for Recycler View?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my APP, a fragment contains a **RecyclerView** which shows the content in a **Grid(initially)**. I Just want to show the content in a List when the user clicks on the Secondary Button on Toolbar. Content is almost same in the both case that's why I am trying to achieve this with one **RecyclerView**/**Adapter**/**Fragment** but I am not getting how to get it done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
    btnChange.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });
```